# Basic Topology: Particular Point Topology

Tags: general-topology

I need to determine the Closure of A, Boundary of A, Interior of A, and Exterior of A, which are Cl(A), Bd(A), Int(A), and Ext(A) respectively.

Let X = R, and T = {U subset of X: 1 is in U or U = empty set}.
Let A = {0,2}.

Here are the items I have noted.
A is not an interval, it is a set containing 0 and 2.

My understanding is that the only closed sets in this topology are sets that do not contain 1 together with X.

I believe Cl(A) is {0,2} because the smallest closed set contain {0,2} is itself.

Set A would be open if it contained 1.  Since {0,2} is a set and not an interval then it does not contain 1.  Therefore A does not contain 1 and there are no non-empty open subsets of A.  Thus Int(A) equals the empty set.

My definitions for Ext(A) and Bd(A) are below.  I am a little confused on how to apply both of these to this topology.

Ext(A) is the set of all points x in X for which there exists an open set U such that x is in U and U is a subset of X - A.

Bd(A) is the set of all points x in X for which every open set containing x intersects A and X - A.

Comment: I think you've got the definition of Ext(A) wrong--that is the definition for Int(A)--it should say that $U$ is a subset of $X\setminus A$. Regarding your work with Int(A): it isn't quite correct to say that $A$ has *no* open subsets, but rather that it has no *non-empty* open subsets.

Comment: I corrected the definition of Ext(A).  Thank you.

Comment: I also corrected the reference to non-empty.  The empty set itself is both open and closed so it would not be correct to say that there are no open sets.  Thank you.

Comment: What you state for the def'n of Ext$(A$) is actually the def'n of Int$(A$)... .I believe Ext(A) is the interior of the complement of $A$, which is equal to the complement of Cl$(A)$........Int($A$) is also equal to the union of all subsets of $A $that are open in $X$..... The boundary Bd($A$) can also be defined as Cl$(A)\cap $Cl$(X\backslash A)$ and is also written $\partial A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure is correct. The interior is empty.

I think your definition of exterior is incorrect, because note that the exterior of any set shouldn't lie within that set. I think the open set $U$ in that definition **should not intersect** $A$. Having said that, every point in $A$ complement satisfies that, because given $x \neq 0,x \neq 2$, you can find some open set around $x$ which doesn't contain $0$  or $2$. I'll leave you to see how this is done, but think about what the diameter of such an open set (usually a ball) would be. So Ext($A$) should be the whole real line except for the points $0$ and $2$.

The boundary of the set is the whole set, I claim. Why? The boundary doesn't intersect the exterior, by definition. However, the boundary doesn't  intersect the interior, by definition. Hence the points $0$ and $2$ are left behind. But surely, every open set around $0$ or $2$ contains zero or two, hence intersecting $A$, and also intersects $X$\ $A$, because that open set will also contain some point which is not zero or two. It follows that the boundary of $A$ is $A$ itself.

These are correct. Please ask if any doubts.

Comment: Thank you.  Your explanation is extremely helpful.

Comment: @NUG you are welcome. Besides, think about the following: Given any set, is the whole space decomposed into it's exterior, it's interior and it's boundary? (which is the case here)